# Outputting parsed JSON results from Google Custom Search in Java

Tags: java, json, gson, google-custom-search

I'm trying to output some results (title, url) from Google Custom Search in Java command line for testing, but I keep getting a  java.io.EOFException error. The compiler lists out the offending line, but I can't figure out what to change, even after spending hours searching for an answer. I took most of the code from an existing question here on Stack Overflow. Any help is appreciated.

```
package google.api.search;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

class GSearch {

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException  {
   String key = ""; //replace with API key
   String qry = ""; // search key word
   String cx = ""; //replace with cx
   URL url = new URL ("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=" +key+ "&cx=" +cx+ "&q=" +qry+ "&alt=json");

   HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
   conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader ( ( conn.getInputStream() ) ) );

   String output;
   {while ((output = br.readLine()) != null){
       GResults results = new Gson().fromJson(output, GResults.class);
       System.out.println(results);
   }   
   conn.disconnect(); 
   }  
   }
}
```

GResults class:

```
public class GResults {

String title;
String link;

public GResults(String title, String link) {
    this.title = title;
    this.link = link;
}

public String getTitle(){
    return title;
}

public String getLink(){
    return link;
}

public void setTitle(String title){
    this.title = title;
}

public void setLink(String link){
    this.link = link;
}

public String toString(){
    return ("Title:%s, Link:%s", title, link);
}   
}
```

Error line:

```
GResults results = new Gson().fromJson(output, GResults.class);
```

Error messages:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 2
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:813)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:689)
at google.api.search.GSearch.main(GSearch.java:26)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 2
at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextNonWhitespace(JsonReader.java:1377)
at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:483)
at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.hasNext(JsonReader.java:403)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:166)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803)
... 4 more
```

Comment: Can you please post the full stack trace, along with the line that the error is appearing on?

Comment: I have added the error messages as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out the main flaw after going through the raw JSON output. Google's JSON was returning an **array** of "items" instead via the `[]` symbols, so after adding a List in the GResults class as so:

```
import java.util.List;

public class GResults {

public String link;
public List<GResults> items;

public String getLink(){
    return link;
}

public List<GResults> getItems(){
    return items;
}

public void setLink(String link){
    this.link = link;
}

public void setGroups(List<GResults> items){
    this.items = items;
}

public void getThing (int i){
    System.out.println(items.get(i));
}

public String toString(){
    return String.format("%s", link);
}

}
```

I was able to return a series of links with the following command in the main GSearch class:

```
   HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
   conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader ( ( conn.getInputStream() ) ) );
   GResults results = new Gson().fromJson(br, GResults.class);

   for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
   results.getThing(i);
```

Answer (score 5):

I think I read it around 20 times before I noticed, Here is proper code

```
    final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(50);
    String output;
    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
        builder.append(output);
    }   
 final  GResults results = new Gson().fromJson(builder.toString(), GResults.class);
```

Gson is throwing proper exception because you were reading line by line and giving that line to gson for de-serializing. For example first line is { or [ or "message": { , and This is not a valid json JsonSyntax.

Enjoy :)

Comment: Tried it out, it gives another error:

`Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object at line 1 column 14813`

For this line of code: 
`final GResults results = new Gson().fromJson(builder.toString(), GResults.class);`

Comment: i think your JSON in not well formed and your need to check your json format is valid go here http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ . can you post your json sample here

Comment: @gwar666 GSON throws that particular error when there's extra characters after the end of the object that aren't whitespace - and it defines whitespace very narrowly (as the JSON spec does) - only \t, \n, \r, and space count as whitespace. If you can't easily figure out what's causing the extra characters at the end and eliminate them, another option is to tell GSON to parse in lenient mode: Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(result1));
reader.setLenient(true);

Comment: I'm getting the JSON directly from the Google custom search API though. I'll try implementing GSON lenient mode.

Comment: try this Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(builder.toString()));
reader.setLenient(true);
GResults result = gson.fromJson(reader, GResults.class);